# Ubuntu 12.04 - libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and I am getting the following error when I try to run DDMS.

Error Output was:

> /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.16' not found (required by /home/ubuntu/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb)

Looks like there are some missing libraries here but not entirely sure. Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: It means the C library on this system is too old, while the application was built against a much newer version. Why do you use 12.04? Something from 2012 is long dead. Even Ubuntu LTS release won't last 8 years.

Comment: I use 12.04 as it is part of Georgia Tech's Ubuntu Virtual Machine Image for some of their courses. It comes with other preinstalled software so not sure if these world still work as intended if I upgrade to say 14.04.

Comment: I see. Then that's a terrible problem caused by the time. Both Ubuntu and Android has moved quickly over the years, so you probably won't be able to redo what's captured in the course materials, but latest Android SDK on latest Ubuntu should continue to work.